# Audio Error in Xcode: "[UIViewController play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" occurring in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I am trying to make a button that when clicked plays audio. This is the code I have for that button and they appear to be connected fine (both the play and stop buttons):

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

// play sounds for meditation
// let whiteNoise = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3HourWhiteNoise", ofType: "mp3")!)
class WellnessViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")
            
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }

        }
    
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
        @IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to click the play button in the simulator, it gives me the following error:

> Exception NSException *   "-[UIViewController play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104d04280" 0x0000600000c683c0

and it opens up the `AppDelegate.swift` file, which has the following code:

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, but it seems like it's something simple I'm just missing. I tried setting the view controller class and button class to the `WellnessViewController` (where the buttons are) but that doesn't seem to be doing much.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: As I think you have identified, the “-[**UIViewController** play:]: unrecognized selector” error [emphasis added] is telling you that it it instantiated a `UIViewController`, and not a `WellnessViewController`, and obviously cannot resolve the `@IBAction` to `play`. Generally this happens when the base class of a view controller in storyboard scene or NIB has not been set correctly. (FYI, the debugger dropping you in the `AppDelegate` is a red herring; don’t worry about that.)

Comment: As an aside, the reference to “I tried setting the … button class to the `WellnessViewController`” is curious, as you shouldn’t be setting the button class at all (or at least, definitely not to `WellnessViewController`). If you manually set the button class, I would reset that back to the default. Fine, hook up the `@IBAction`, but don’t change its class. If, when hooking up the button action, you are not automatically seeing `WellnessViewController` in your assistant editor, that suggests that, again, the base class for the view controller has not been set correctly.

Comment: @Rob Glad to hear it is a red herring because I definitely panicked a bit. It looks like actually the button class did not change - so it's just the default right now. I did change the view controller class to WellnessViewController, but it autocompletes to UIWellnessViewController regardless of how I enter it. Could that be another issue? Changing the code to match it with UIWellnessViewController? Update: tried that and it definitely was not the answer.

Comment: That’s weird as there is no `UIWellnessViewController`, AFAIK. I might advise closing the project, emptying the "derived data" folder, and the quit and restart Xcode. If you are still seeing `UIWellnessViewController` in autocomplete, I'd suggest searching the project (command-shift-o, for example) for that symbol. Re not finding `WellnessViewController`, make sure that swift file is included for your target.

Comment: @Rob (first, thank you so much for your help so far) I deleted everything in the "derived data" folder, restarted Xcode, and it was still appearing as UIWellnessViewController. I searched the project for it, and the only thing coming up is that ViewController. If I click the first orange symbol above the viewfinder, the class is WellnessViewController. But, if I click on the view controller itself it goes back to UIWellnessViewController. And it still corrects itself. I believe the WellnessViewController is included for my target? It's on the same level as the other ViewControllers.

Comment: Try to check/uncheck the "Inherit Module from Target", sometimes it helps when setting the class in Storyboard. But in other words, as long as the class in Storyboard for the VC isn't correctly set as `WellnessViewController`, it will crash.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a new blank project and try it again. See if you can reproduce the problem. And if you’re still having problems, upload the project where we can take a look at it. But I just created a view controller named `WellnessViewController`, set the scene’s view controller’s base class to `WellnessViewController`, hooked up the buttons, and it worked fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNKDA.png